# How to call the CITES species+ api in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am trying to access the cites species api to get information on a input species name.

Reference document: http://api.speciesplus.net/documentation/v1/references.html

I tried to use the api with the provided API Key.

I get error code 401.

Here is the code

```
import requests

APIKEY='XXXXXXXXXXXX' # Replaced with provided api key
r = requests.get('https://api.speciesplus.net/api/v1/taxon_concepts.xml?name=Mammalia&X-Authentication-Token={APIKEY}')
r
```

Comment: Headers and query parameters aren't the same thing...

Comment: first you could display `print( r.text )` to see what you get for server - you may get messaga with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said in comment:

```
"Headers and query parameters aren't the same thing..."
```

You have to set `APIKEY` as `header` - don't put it in `URL`.

You may also put parameters as dictionary and `requests` will append them to `URL` - and code will be more readable.

```
import requests

APIKEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

headers = {
    "X-Authentication-Token": APIKEY,
}

payload = {
   "name": "Mammalia",
}

url = "https://api.speciesplus.net/api/v1/taxon_concepts.xml"

response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you skip `.xml` in URL then you get data as JSON and it can be more useful

```
url = "https://api.speciesplus.net/api/v1/taxon_concepts"

response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)

data = response.json()

for item in data:
    print(item['citation'])
```

Comment: headers = {
    "X-Authentication-Token": APIKEY,
} should be renamed as 'header', as it was assigned as headers= header in response.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected `header` to `hearders`